# Setting size of Buttons in TableRow

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a(probably) banal but annoying problem. I have `TableRow`. In the Row there are 9 Buttons, but only 5 of them are visible. if I shorten the code, it will look like this:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="fill_vertical">

<TableRow
android:id="@+id/row"/>

</TableLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokusy);
    TableRow row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        Button b = new Button(this);
        row.addView(b);
    }
}}
```

I've already tried whatever I found on the internet(like for instance .`setWidth`, `setLayoutParams`, `android:layout_width="..."`), but still only 5 of the 9 Buttons are visible on the screen.
Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Could you post the whole of your XML?

Comment: You know... I have a long xml and long java code. Actually I have 9 TableRows with 9 Buttons in each of them. But, as I have already written... only 5 were visible(in each row), so I said to myself, I will try to do an experiment and I made a new 'experiment' class where the xml code looks exactly like the code above.

Comment: I just tested your code and it seems to draw 9 buttons in the first row. Its doing exactly what you're telling it to do by this code

Comment: I thing it might do that, but at my device it doesn't and I don't know how is it possible.

Comment: This might sound a bit stupid/rude but did you try and view it in landscape as well?

Comment: I can't...setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);...that's because in my final product I wanna have that only portrait-orientated

Answer (score 1):

Modified your XML a little to make it work. The shrinkColumns attribute makes the column fit to the desired `TableLayout` parameters. The '*' applies it to all the columns.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:shrinkColumns="*" > <!-- this makes the difference -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Still it doesn't work. I really don't know why. Still 5 are visible and the 6th is visible only partly. I'd like to send you my printscreen that you can see that, but I don't know how.

Comment: Did you add the TableRow layout params to the XML?

Comment: This code is working correctly. The only explanation is that there's something wrong in the rest of your code which is hindering in the TableLayout drawing properly.